# How to change the favicon of an OpenCPU application?

Tags: favicon, opencpu, rapache

I would like to add a custom favicon to my OpenCPU app. Although I manually set the favicon to be a custom image, it gets override by the default cloud icon from OpenCPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCPU overrides the favicon in `/var/www/html` by its default favicon. This default favicon is stored at `/usr/lib/opencpu/rapache/favicon.ico`, so you just have to change that file and from now on, it will show your custom favicon.